# how to set different value for host in http header with host in url in golang

Tags: http, curl, go, http-headers

I can use `curl` to send my request successfully, but golang seems impossible to do.

```
curl -H 'Host: aaa.com' 'http://bbb.com'
```

My question is: how I can send request with host which is different with host in url?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set [Request.Host](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Host) to change the host header sent to the server.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://bbb.com/", nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
req.Host = "aaa.com"
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/f_VAEzdKfW9)

Comment: Cheers. It's confusing though why setting `Host` header does not suffice here.

Comment: @YanFoto The net/http package uses the Request.Host field to represent the `Host` header instead of the `"Host"` member of Request.Header.  This special treatment of the header is a bit confusing, but that's the way it works.